# How to change function from firing on press to firing when app loads

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a weather app that gets the user's location when they open the app. I was given starter code that uses a button that gets the user's location when it's pressed. How can do I change the code so that it fires the contents of the _onPress function when the app is opened?

My starter code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    import Button from "./../Button";
    import styles from "./style.js";

    const style = { backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD" };

    class LocationButton extends Component {
      _onPress() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          initialPosition => {
            this.props.onGetCoords(
              initialPosition.coords.latitude,
              initialPosition.coords.longitude
            );
          },
          error => {
            alert(error.message);
          },
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Button
            label="Use Current Location"
            style={style}
            onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    export default LocationButton;
```

I had read that componentWillMount() will fire before render, so I tried inserting the following code after the _onPress() function, but I got an error stating 'Can't find variable: _onPress'

```
componentWillMount() {
   _onPress();
}
```

I'm sure the solution is simple - I'm very new to ReactNative. I will gladly give any additional information if need be. Thank you!

Comment: the starter code that's on `_inPress` has to be executed on the `Loading` screen... and you don't redirect to your main flow of your app, until you get the location successfully

Answer (score 0):

`_onPress()` doesn't exist because it's not bound to anything until the render method. Just`_onPress()` actually doesn't exist anywhere. To fix this, change`_onPress()` to an arrow function by changing the function declaration from `_onPress(){}` to `_onPress = () => {}`, then call it in `componentDidMount` via `this._onPress()`. You'll also have to change your `onPress` to `onPress={this._onPress`}. The second way of fixing this still requires you to change your `onPress` to `onPress={this._onPress`}, but also to create a constructor and bind your function there by doing `this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)`.